# Determine the shell from which screen reattach was called

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, process-management

I'm trying to determine whether a command I'm running is within an SSH session. Usually this works fine by checking for `$SSH_CONNECTION` or walking the process tree and looking for `sshd`.
However, if I start a `screen` session locally and then re-attach it through SSH, neither of those works.

Is there some way from within the reattached screen session to determine which shell the session is currently attached to?
The process tree just looks like `shell(X) --> screen(Y) --> systemd(1)`, which makes sense, since the screen session probably gets reparented when I exit the local terminal.

`screen -ls` does not say anything more than `(Attached)`, with only the PID `Y`, no helpful PID of where it is currently attached.

The process tree of `shell(A)` where it is attached includes a single child `screen(B)`, but I cannot find a way to link the PIDs `Y` and `B`. I even tried to find the other end of the unix socket being used by screen but it comes up empty. (even checked as `root`).

Is this just something that isn't possible?

Comment: `ps waux | grep screen` might be useful. You could grep against user. Depending on your version/OS, `who` might be helpful.

Comment: Is perhaps `tty` , which will show you the terminal shell running in the `screen` , or  `ps T` which will show you the currently running processes only within the current shell, something that you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those really help. tty printed `dev/pts/3` from inside screen, but there's no way to link that to the screen process that initiated the re-attach.

ps did list the process with the re-attach command, but that would require argument parsing in a manner that won't really scale.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and I think what you are looking for is `ps -q $(ps h -q $(($$-1)) -o ppid) -o tty,cmd,pid` which will give you the `tty` and `pid` of the original shell  that invoked `screen`

Comment: @BarBar1234 that won't work after re-attach. Of course during the initial screen run I can just walk the process tree. But after I disconnect and re-attach, the parent is systemd(1) and there is no relationship between the screen that re-attached and the screen running the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, here's what I ended up with:

- Find the screen the shell is running under. Keep walking the pstree until a screen process is found:
  `screen_pid=$(pstree -psUA $$ | egrep -o 'screen\([0-9]+\)' | tail -1 | egrep -o '[0-9]+')`
- Look at all opened files for that process. Find the only /dev/pts/* file in that list:
  `screen_pts=$(lsof -p $screen_pid | grep /dev/pts | awk '{print $NF}')`
- Find the screen process controlling that psuedo-terminal:
  `ps -o pid=,tty= -C screen | grep ${screen_pts/\/dev\/} | awk '{print $1}'`
- From there the parent process will be the shell/ssh/whatever started the screen which is *now* attached to the shell.

There are definitely some hacky assumptions made here that "work on my machine(tm)", but that's the general idea.

If reliability is required, using `stat` with `st_rdev` will eliminate the hacky /dev/pts/5 -> pts/5 replacement. And something similar could be used to filter the list of open files where `major(st_rdev)` == some value that represents pseudo terminals.